# PhoneGap - iFrame won't load on iOS - Possibly a Whitelist issue?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe

I am relatively new to PhoneGap.I have a standard "HelloWorld" template (no settings changed) where I add an iFrame to https://bite.rip/start.php and it loads perfectly in Android. When I try it on iOS however, the iFrame (border) is visible but the page doesn't load (content remains empty). From my low knowledge in this area, I am guessing I need to add some whitelisting or something. HOW can I make iframes show up in iOS too?

Note: I have checked out several similar questions, but their answers are not solving my problem. (Usually the other topics concern "cross-domain" errors on server-side or the Asker is being referred to other solutions such as inappview.)

Comment: Did you have whitelist plugin installed ?

Comment: May be there is a issue related to plugin.
Did you add whitelist plugin in project ?

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: AFAIK white-list plugin is not supported in iOS. You need to add App Transport Security Exception Domains in info.plist